# Points at equal interval in Svg Path

Tags: javascript, math, svg

i am working on svg based application where user draw a path and i convert that path to points by using following function

```
path2Array: function(path, incrementer) {

                        var pointsArray = new Array();
                        var add = 1;
                        var point, tx, ty, cordinatesXY;
                        if (incrementer)
                                add = incrementer;

                        var length = Math.ceil(path.getTotalLength());

                        for (var i = 0; i <= length; i += add) {
                                point = path.getPointAtLength(i);
                                tx = Paper.roundDecimalNumber(point.x);// custom rounding function
                                ty = Paper.roundDecimalNumber(point.y);
                                cordinatesXY = {
                                        x: tx,
                                        y: ty
                                }

                                pointsArray.push(cordinatesXY);
                        }


                        return pointsArray;
                }
```

Now , i want to get points in equal interval.

For example, let say in an svg path, my function returns an array which have

Total_nodes=200;

now i want 5 nodes at equal distance, so i divide 200/5=40;

```
for(var i=0;i<points.length;i+=40)
{
var point=points[i];
// do something
}
```

and i loop the points array with '40' increment to get 5 points at equal interval.

What didn't work, is when nodes are 212. now if i divide 212/5=42.4 (not an integer index). So now how i can get points at equal interval if i get index in decimal point.

Comment: you meant points[42.4] will return points?  No , i already tried.

Comment: Is there a a reason you need to pull your 5 points from the array and not use `getPointAtLength(distance)` to pull them from the path?

Comment: thanks Jason for the reply, actually i need array of points. But let me check your suggestion and try getPointAtLEngth(d) directly